# change keyboard event to mouse event as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mouseevent

I am a new new person who learn action script 3.

i have problem when i convert keyboard event to mouse event when i moving a walking character.

when use the keyboard event i have no problem. this is my code

```
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    var speed:Number=2;
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, stikman);
    function stikman(e:KeyboardEvent)
     {
      if (e.keyCode==Keyboard.LEFT)
       {
        stik.x-=speed;
        stik.scaleX=-1;
        stik.stik2.play();
       }
      else if (e.keyCode==Keyboard.RIGHT)
       {
        stik.x+=speed;
        stik.scaleX=1;
        stik.stik2.play();
       }
      }
```

and then i try to change keyboard event to mouse event when moving character with button it should press click, click and click. i want to hold the click when moving the character and when mouse up the character stop. but i still don't know how. this my code when i try to change to mouse event

```
     var speed:Number=2;
     mundur.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, stikman);
     function stikman(e:MouseEvent)
      {
       stik.x-=speed;
       stik.scaleX=-1;
       stik.stik2.play();
      }
     maju.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stikman2);
     function stikman2(e:MouseEvent)
      {
        stik.x+=speed;
        stik.scaleX=1;
        stik.stik2.play();
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because keyboard produces **KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN** event repeatedly as long as key is pressed, while **MouseEvent.CLICK** as well as **MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN** are dispatched only once per user action.

With mouse you need to change the logic.

```
// Subscribe both buttons.
ButtonRight.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onButton);
ButtonLeft.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onButton);

var currentSpeed:Number = 0;
var isPlaying:Boolean = false;

function onButton(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Set up the directions and start the animation.
    switch (e.currentTarget)
    {
        case ButtonLeft:
            currentSpeed = -speed;
            stik.stik2.play();
            stik.scaleX = -1;
            break;

        case ButtonRight:
            currentSpeed = speed;
            stik.stik2.play();
            stik.scaleX = 1;
            break;
    }

    isPlaying = true;

    // Call repeatedly to move character.
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);

    // Hook the MOUSE_UP even even if it is outside the button or even stage.
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp);
}

function onFrame(e:Even):void
{
    // Move character by the designated offset each frame.
    stik.x += currentSpeed;

    if (!isPlaying)
    {
        // Stop at last frame.
        // if (stik.stik2.currentFrame == stik.stik2.totalFrames)

        // Stop at frame 1.
        if (stik.stik2.currentFrame == 1)
        {
            // Stop the animation.
            stik.stik2.stop();

            // Stop moving.
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);
        }
    }
}

function onUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Indicate to stop when the animation ends.
    isPlaying = false;

    // Unhook the MOUSE_UP event.
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer sir, its right. but when mouse up i want the character still walk and then stop to the first position. can you help me again sir?

Comment: @BagasPR Do not unsubscribe from Event.ENTER_FRAME then and do not stop the animation.

Comment: i have tried before sir, but i still can't do that. i don't understand what you mean because i still new for this :D. can't you explain more specified?. when mouse down the character walk and when mouse up character still walk until end of frame and then back and stop to the first frame (first position). thanks before

Comment: @BagasPR Then you need to update the **ENTER_FRAME** handler to watch the animation and stop moving if user is no longer pressing the mouse button and animation is at right frame. I updated my post.

Comment: i have tried your code sir, it's work, but when mouse up why the character still walk sir? can you help me again? thanks before

Comment: sorry sir your code is right just my fault. thank you very much sir